# How does neighbor know when WiFi/Internet is used?

Tags: network, wifi, internet, user-tracking

A neighbor, somehow, knows, when I connect to the Internet - and begins shooting something at my home (ice pellets).  Is there a way to prevent people from seeing my SSID/internet connection?  We are on cable Internet;  I heard that was akin to a party line.

Comment: Obligatory skeptical comment: How sure are you that they know when you log on to the Internet? Have you tried closing your curtains? What do you mean by "log on to" -- do you mean just getting on to wifi? Is this your own home Internet or are you logging on to your neighbors?

Comment: or, do you and your neighbor both use the same shared wifi service?

Comment: Agree with @FireQuacker  Indeed, most people don't ever "logon" to the internet.  Typically your home router is always connected to the internet, as are most of your devices (certainly phones, most desktop computers, some laptops).  Therefore the concept of "logging on" isn't really applicable anymore.  If you have an issue with your neighbor shooting ice pellets at your house, I would worry about dealing with that and not worry about "when" they shoot them...

Comment: Do you connect over a WiFi Network to your cable modem?

Comment: It's my personal pc, in my home, my modem/ router/ Spectrum cable and I don't share..  Window-blinds are closed.  Only when I connect to the Internet  - does shooting ice-pellets begin - one area of home.  It never happens unless I go online.  Law enforcement has no evidence of ice pellets shot from a gun; it melts.   It can be every minutes or every couple minutes.  When I go outside, it stops.  MARCEL:

Answer (score 3):

Since you are talking about SSID, I assume you connect over a WiFi Network to your cable modem.

**WiFi is open in the sense that anyone can listen to the packets anyone exchanges with the WiFi access point, even when the connection is encrypted.**

It only requires a WiFi network card/USB Stick etc. working in promiscuous mode, and you can see all packets in the air, of any network. With this, it's possible not only to see whether a device connects to any network, but which device, for how long, and how much data it exchanges.

This has been done for various purposes, one is to keep track of employee's work hours.

Here's more information about the topic, but a quick google will reveal much more: https://www.howtogeek.com/196998/your-devices-broadcast-unique-numbers-and-theyre-being-used-to-track-you/

Comment: Thank you, all, for your generous responses.  My cell-phone wifi is turned off, always - as is Bluetooth (police, etc. creating false cell towers):  https://www.rt.com/usa/184636-fake-cell-phone-towers/

Answer (score -1):

The only reasonable way I can think of to perform this idea, would be that your neighbor somehow has access to your network or one of your devices, while he's inside your network he's able to know how many devices are turned on because they have an IP.

In another scenario we can assume also he has access to one of your devices remotely, in this case a computer for example, which once it's online it will be available to be monitored remotely by your neighbor in the imaginary scenario where he compromised your computer.

At last in the worst scenario, he's constantly watching you through your windows or possibly with remote wifi cameras he installed in the possible scenario where you invited him to your house, went for a leak and he quickly installed a remote wifi camera running to see yours wifi's password and installing into a secret place where it's available to see if you're sitting by your computer, therefor he'll be able to see if you're using the internet.

Also he could've access to your router, on this other scenario we can assume that you didn't setup any new ceredentials for your router and it had default password, which is a known vulnerability in a lot of ISPs.

Well Think about it, try to talk to your neighbor he might be doing something illegal, or he's just a rebel human that wishes you to feel his attention using ice pellets against your house which could be the best scenario hopefully really

Comment: No one was in my home, unless it was NSA while I was out.  No one has/ had access to my pc.  I bought a different pc and it continued.  I don't know which "neighbor" is shooting at my home.  I read about guns and ice bullets, online... they melt.  I have a commercial router and have changed the admin/ passwords every week to every 2 months/ changed the SSID name/ IP, numerous times; blocked outgoing modem traffic.  Outside cameras don't pick up the ice pellets, but zinging the camera shakes it.  Remote access is turned off.

Comment: Sounds like you're facing a supernatural techy savvy creature, I advice you to get some spiritual advice, jks, tbh I can't think of something else but casualty according to your scenario specifications

Comment: Magic and religion were created because people couldn't explain the explainable.  If not taught to question, a response would not be of any help.  Research ice bullets and ask cable techs about their "party-line".  Ever see Edward Snowdon movie?  If YOU is in the response, it might be akin to a personal attack rather than helping to solve a puzzle.

Comment: For example:  Heart Attack Gun (HAG) is a weapon that was revealed in 1975 at a hearing of a committee led by Frank Church. At the hearing, Church showed off the CIA's heart attack gun, which was a modified Colt 1911. The gun is electrically powered by a battery and fires an extremely small bullet of ice with frozen shellfish toxin in the centre. Question because no one is omnipotent  https://citizentruth.org/cia-heart-attack-gun/